# parsing json array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have been trying to parse a json array with no success.  I can get a root element but not any array elements.  Below is the beginning of my json array from Foursquare which has re-occurring venue elements.

```
     response: {
          keywords: {}
          suggestedRadius: 10000
          headerLocation: "here"
          headerFullLocation: "here"
          headerLocationGranularity: "unknown"
          headerMessage: "Suggestions for Friday evening"
          totalResults: 214
             groups: [
               {
                  type: "Recommended Places"
                  name: "recommended"
                  items: [
                      {
                       reasons: {
                       count: 0
                       items: [ ]
                        }
                       venue: {
                            id: "4b799a05f964a520b1042fe3"
                            name: "Green Gables"
                            contact: {
                            phone: "3097472496"
                            formattedPhone: "(309) 747-2496"
                                  }
                            location: {
                            address: "17485 East 2500 North Rd"
```

Below is my PHP code to try to get the name of the restaurants.

```
   $obj = json_decode($uri, true);

   foreach($obj['response']['groups'] as $p)
   {
   if(isset($p['items']))
   {
     foreach($p['items'] as $p1)
 {
  if(isset($p1['venue']))
  {
//   echo varDumpToString($p1['venue']);  // this dump works ok and shows the elements
 foreach($p1['venue'] as $p2)
 {

     echo varDumpToString($p2['name']);   //  This is where I get the error
   }
   }
   }
   }   
   }
```

The program drills down to the name element and then gives me an error saying "Unefined index: name" and also 'Illegal string offset name".  This message appears 14 times which is one time for each item in the array.  So why is "name" not recognized?

Comment: When you decoded your json using json_decode(), did you return it as an array or object?

If object, try using $p2->name.

Comment: Are you sure that node is converted to an `array`, not a `stdObject`? In that case you can access the name via `$p2->name`

Comment: LOL @AdrianCrepaz beat me to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.groups[x].items[y].venue` is not an array. You are currently trying to access `response.groups[x].items[y].venue[z].name`, but you are actually accessing `response.groups[x].items[y].venue.id.name`, which does not exist. That last `foreach` iterates over the venue properties, not the venues. There is only one venue for each item.

This is what it should look like:

```
$obj = json_decode($uri, true);

foreach ($obj['response']['groups'] as $group) {
    if (isset($group['items'])) {
        foreach ($group['items'] as $item) {
            if (isset($item['venue'])) {
                echo varDumpToString($item['venue']['name']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what should my last foreach look like?  I tried about every combination I can think of.  Why am I accessing venue.id.name.  I thought id and name were separate elements.  I just want to get id and name as separate items.

Comment: @Dave - Check out my example. There is only a single venue for each item, so you cannot iterate them. You should also try to use more descriptive names for your variables to improve readability. This makes it a lot easier to catch errors like this.

Comment: If I do 'echo varDumpToString($p2['venu']['name'] I will get the name but it repeats itself 14 times for each venue.  How can I just get the name as a singleton?

Comment: @Dave - I am not sure what exactly you are doing, but I suspect the following: If all items have the same venue, the name is obviously displayed multiple times.

Comment: @elusive - Thanks very much for your suggestion.  It worked great!  I am a newbie to PHP and it was impossible to find an example of what I was trying to do.  Now I know and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line,

```
 foreach($p1['venue'] as $p2)
```

to

```
 foreach($p1['venue'] as $p2Key => $p2)
```

Comment: This is not going to help. `$p2` will contain `4b799a05f964a520b1042fe3` in the first case, so accessing the `name` property of that string does not make a lot of sense. This is exactly why OPs code does not work.